# Add key to hash if condition is true

Tags: javascript

I've got this code:

```
function myFunction(serializeData, extraSerializedData){
  //serializeData is boolean
  var    formSerializedData = '';
  if(serializeData){
      var formSerializedData = $("#myform").serialize();
      if (typeof extraSerializedData !== 'undefined'){
        formSerializedData += extraSerializedData;
      }
    }

    $.ajax({
      type: "get",
      url: "/123",
      data: formSerializedData, //TODO!!!       
      success: function(data){
        //......
```

I want to add the `data` key only if `serializeData` exists. Is it possible and how to do this in a way that the code remains "beautiful"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest, though untested:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "get",
      url: "/123",
      data: serializeData !== undefined ? formSerializedData : null,
      success: function(data){
        //......
      }
});
```

Comment: the key of data will exist anyway, it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: there is also extraSerializedData

Comment: If `serializeData` does not exist then then the key will be `null`, and not sent/submitted. The key will be created, yes, but associated with a `null` value, and effectively unset.

Comment: Ok, and what do you want to *do* with `extraSerializedData`?

Comment: In what way does that complicate anything? What is about `extraSerializedData` that you're asking about?

Comment: extraSerializedData = "&button_name=fdsfdsfdsfds&radio_name=fdgfdg23232";

Answer (score 1):

I hate ternary operators, so here, have this:

```
function myFunction(serializeData, extraSerializedData){
    var formSerializedData = '';
    var extendWith = {};

    if(serializeData){
        var formSerializedData = $("#myform").serialize();
        if (typeof extraSerializedData !== 'undefined'){
            formSerializedData += extraSerializedData;
        }
        extendWith.data = formSerializedData;
    }

    $.ajax($.extend({
        type: "get",
        url: "/123",    
        success: function(data){
            //......
        }
        //rest of the object
    },extendWith));
}
```

Comment: But this way you can add other keys to the `extendWith` object.

Comment: Why do you hate ternary operators?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest use ajaxSetUp :

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
     url: "/123/",
     type: "get",
     success: function(){};
   });

   //Check for serializeData data and pass accordingly
  $.ajax({ data: myData });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFunction(serializeData, extraSerializedData){
    var ajaxthing = {
        type: 'get', 
        url: '/123', 
        success: function (data) {...}
    };

    if(serializeData){
        var formSerializedData = $("#myform").serialize();
        if (typeof extraSerializedData !== 'undefined'){
            formSerializedData += extraSerializedData;
        }
        ajaxthing.data = formSerializedData;
    }

    $.ajax(ajaxthing);
```